# Как локальный json с помощью(XHR) записать в store redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Не пойму как это правильно реализовать. Мне нужно локальный файл json с помощью асинхронного запроса (XHR), например fetch распарсить и поместить в store redux-а. Может я что то усложняю. Хочу чтобы легко было изменить локальный json на API url.

За любые советы всем спасибо.

P.S. React и Redux только учу

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import Clients from './clients.json';

import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

function clients(state = []) {
    return state
}

const store = createStore(clients); // This is reducers

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: вы хотите, что бы при инициализации приложения данные записывались в стор? или просто что бы была загрузка этих данных. Просто где у вас экшены для изменения редьюсера?

Comment: экшен мне пока не нужен, я не буду изменять данные, а только читать. Я хотел, чтобы данные сразу записывались в стор. Но может я как то неправильно понимаю принцип работы редакса.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете Create React App, можно поместить JSON-файл в папку public и обращаться к нему по пути '/you-file.json'.

Comment: Подскажите еще, а могу я с помощью `fetch` получить массив и локального файла?